# Ubuntu 19.04 not booting after BIOS update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 on a P1 Thinkpad (bought 2019)

I updated all my software through the software manager. One of the updates was for my BIOS.

When I next opened my laptop and it came out of hibernation and the BIOS updated completed successfully.

The laptop rebooted, the splash screen came up then I saw the following message briefly before the screen went black.

```
Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

I have looked through the BIOS setting to see if anything has been reset to factory settings, but everything looks fine.

Does anyone know where to start to try and fix this?
Do I need to reinstall the OS again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot more googling, I worked out that the BIOS has lost the location of the EFI file.

I found this walk though on YouTube that goes step by step to add the location of the EFI file back into the BIOS

https://youtu.be/MN-Q5h2Iv8A

Hope this helps someone else